# Pressure energy to Electric energy

Tags: efficient-energy-use

Is the pressure energy can be converted  into electric energy? Like pressure energy of vehicles on a bridge can be converted into electric energy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Pessure energy* is not a common term. Because where is the energy exactly that you want to convert to electric energy?

A good rule of thumb is that in order for energy to be converted, something must *move*. If the road pavement would bend as the car drives over it then you could theoretically draw energy out of it.

But there do though exist several phenomenon that do not  require macroscale movements to convert energy, like solar cells, fuel cells, the thermoelectric effect, and the piezoelectric effect.

And the [piezoelectric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezoelectricity) might be of interest in your case - this is *Vibrations* or *mechanical stress* turned into electric energy directly. I remember that this has been tried on dance floors on some discos in South Korea.